# How can I open the keyboard on my Android tablet?

Tags: keyboard

I have just bought a NATPC M009S ULTIMATE Capacative Android Tablet PC Android 4.0 ICS and I can't find any way of accessing the keyboard.

How can I open it?

Answer (score 1):

It should pop up when you tap on a text box.
If it doesn't, does there appear a small keyboard icon in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Wow,that was quick. I don't have a text box or a small keyboard icon!

Comment: I can now access the keyboard,thank you, but when I try to enter my BT password to connect to my Wi-Fi,there is no way to get the keyboard back,to do that! Perhaps the battery is too low? I will put it on for 6 hours and see if that makes a difference.Many thanks again.

Comment: I have sussed it all now! Very many thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It should pop up when you hold the menu button. I don't know if this works on tablets with Android 3.0 or higher but it will work on Android 2.1, 2.2 & 2.3.
Good luck!